# React render/update canvas

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas

I'm learning react and I'm trying to render canvas from react and update it every time the state have been change.

```
//set initial state
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imgFile: this.props.imgFile,
      show: false
    };
}

//The render canvas
render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-sm-4">
        <canvas ref={(c) => { this.myCanvas = c; }} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

My question is: Is there any way to update canvas by the props? so far I got this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const origin = this.state.imgFile;
    // canvas area/img calculations
    this.funcForDrawCanvas(origin.path, origin.presition, origin.height, origin.width);
}
```

but after it been the component been mount doesn't update it any more any idea? or is there a way to remove the canvas tag and put it again when the state is change ?

Comment: Make sure to read what each of the component specs do. There are many ways to accomplish this but how about initializing the canvas on [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), check for prop changes using [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) and do canvas rendering on [`componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentdidupdate).

Comment: @Dom can you give me a example of  how ca canvas can be redraw with img?

Comment: Here is the answer you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786505/what-is-correct-lifecycle-method-in-react-16-3-to-update-canvas-from-props/49803151#49803151

Answer (score 2):

Use `componentWillReceiveProps` to detect changes in props and then use that to draw on the canvas.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Yes, now that it is deprecated, the docs suggest using `componentDidUpdate()` instead.  Good catch @Zack