# What is correct lifecycle method in React 16.3 to update canvas from props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, lifecycle

I have a Canvas component, which looks approximately like this:

```js
class Canvas extends React.Component{

    saveRef = node => {
        this._canvas = node;
    }
    
    shouldComponentUpdate(){
        /*I will never re-render this component*/
        return false;
    }
    
    componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ){
        /*Here I do manipulations with this._ctx, when new props come*/
    }
    
    render(){
        return (
            <canvas ref={this.saveRef} />
        );
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        this._ctx = this._canvas.getContext( "2d" );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

React community began to deprecate `componentWillReceiveProps` in order to replace it with `getDerivedStateFromProps`. I can use `componentDidUpdate` to perform my drawings, but then I need to remove `shouldComponentUpdate` and I will have a lot of useless render calls. What is the correct performant way to update my component in react 16.3, when new props come?

Comment: Can `Canvas` component provides some methods to handle the job to draw, and the one knows when should it updates is its parent component. So `Canvas` component never update until the parent does call it. Will this work for you?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the options, but it has two cons: firstly, if Canvas component is connected to redux, it depends on store updates, not on parent, and secondly, you should move update logic to other component. Is there a way to handle new props without re-rendering component? This situation may happen not only with canvas element. For example your component renders 6 containers, which are connected to redux. In this case component also doesn't need to re-render.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `componentDidUpdate` for DOM manipulations like this. A `shouldComponentUpdate` won’t really make a difference for a component with a single child that always has the same props. So you should be able to remove it without a significant difference in performance.

*If you've profiled the application* and determined that in this particular case it *does* make a difference, you can hoist the element into constructor.

This way React will skip over it completely (which effectively works the same way as `shouldComponentUpdate`):

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._ctx = null;
    this._child = <canvas ref={node => {
      this._ctx = node ? node.getContext('2d') : null
    } />;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    // Manipulate this._ctx here
  }

  render() {
    // A constant element tells React to never re-render
    return this._child;
  }
}
```

You could also split it into two components:

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
  saveContext = ctx => {
    this._ctx = ctx;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    // Manipulate this._ctx here
  }

  render() {
    return <PureCanvas contextRef={this.saveContext} />;
  }
}


class PureCanvas extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <canvas
        ref={node => node ? this.props.contextRef(node.getContext('2d') : null)}
      />;
  }
}
```

Comment: @AlexFomin I wanted to add the two following points: arrow functions inside the render method will be created on every render (leads to bad performance). But the arrow function inside the render method here is ok because the component will never update. Furthermore .getContext() returns a context or null. It may return null if you have requested a different context before. Normally you have to check for the null but here it isn't really needed because PureCanvas delivers the same context (with this implementation you can't request another one).

Answer (score 0):

I found this because I had a sort of similar problem but not completely the same. The solution that works for me is just to put all the relevant code in `shouldComponentUpdate`:

(the `if` statement used to be in `componentWillReceiveProps`)

```
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) { // no more random renders
    if (
      (nextProps.nightMode !== this.props.nightMode) ||
      (nextProps.language  !== this.props.language)
    ) {
      this.props.setRefresh(true)                       // setTimeout means after current operation
      setTimeout(() => this.props.setRefresh(false), 1) // so loading will show for longer than 1ms
    }

    return this.props.refresh !== nextProps.refresh
  }
```